# Interactive plots in PyCharm result in the plot window "not responding"

Tags: python, windows, matplotlib, pycharm

I have to use PyCharm Community. By using matplotlib library I tried to draw some graphics but the popup screen of graphic is not responding. I make a research and the solution of matplotlib is `plt.show(block=True)`. Do anyone find another solution to this situation. I don't want to write `block=True` each time.

[image]

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd
import seaborn as sns
df = sns.load_dataset("titanic")
pd.set_option("display.max_columns",None)
pd.set_option("display.width",500)
df.head()
plt.boxplot(df["fare"])    
plt.show(block=True)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had a similar problem with [EOmaps](https://github.com/raphaelquast/EOmaps) and collected some possible workarounds in the docs ([here](https://eomaps.readthedocs.io/en/latest/FAQ.html#pycharm-ide))

A possible solution is to force matplotlib to use its native backend (pycharm hooks in its own backend as far as i know)
by using something like this at the beginning of the script:

```py
import matplotlib
matplotlib.use("qt5agg")
```